# How to check if my postfix was compiled with sasl support?

Tags: centos, postfix, fedora, sasl

I keep reading everywhere that postfix must be compiled with sasl support to be able to use the sasl authentication.

I already have postfix instances running (Centos 6.4 and Fedora 18 machines). They were installed using the package manager (yum).

How can I check if postfix was compiled with sasl support?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`postconf -a` and `postconf -A` tell you what sasl plugin types are available. I would assume those would return errors or empty lists if sasl support was not enabled at build time (though possibly not).

You could also check the output of `ldd /path/to/postfix` and see if it links to a sasl library or not (though it might be possible for postfix to be built with sasl and not link to a sasl library if it supports it via a plugin or something, I don't know whether it does or not).

Comment: Thanks! So I guess it's all good: `ldd /usr/sbin/postfix | grep sasl` outputs `libsasl2.so.2 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f41dda20000)`
`postconf -a` returns
`cyrus
dovecot` and `postconf -A` returns just `cyrus`.

Comment: That matches up with what I see locally and should mean you are fine. The ultimate test of course is to try it and see.